# Combine two lists: aggregate values that have similar keys

Tags: python

I have two lists or more than . Some thing like this:

```
listX = [('A', 1, 10), ('B', 2, 20), ('C', 3, 30), ('D', 4, 30)]
listY = [('a', 5, 50), ('b', 4, 40), ('c', 3, 30), ('d', 1, 20), 
         ('A', 6, 60), ('D', 7, 70])
```

i want to get the result that move the duplicate elements like this:
my result is to get all the list from listX + listY,but in the case there are duplicated
for example
the element `('A', 1, 10), ('D', 4, 30)` of listX is presented or exitst in listY.so the result so be like this

```
result = [('A', 7, 70), ('B', 2, 20), ('C', 3, 30), ('D', 11, 100),
          ('a', 5, 50), ('b', 4, 40), ('c', 3, 30), ('d', 1, 20)]
```

`(A, 7, 70)` is obtained by adding `('A', 1, 10)` and `('A', '6', '60')` together

Anybody could me to solve this problem.?
Thanks.

Comment: This is unreadable. Please format the text.

Comment: Please edit this so it A.) Uses the syntax highlighter/editor and B.) is semi legible. I'm struggling to understand the question

Comment: Please spend some time to make the text readable.

Comment: this is not already readable.

Comment: Is ordering important in the final list?

Comment: ('A', 1, 10), ('D', 4, 30) are not present in both lists so why are they duplicated?

Comment: Evidently the first item in the tuple is a key. He should probably use dictionaries the whole way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using lists like a dictionary. Any reason you're using lists instead of dictionaries?

My understanding of this garbled question, is that you want to add up values in tuples where the first element in the same.

I'd do something like this:

```
counter = dict(
    (a[0], (a[1], a[2]))
    for a in listX
)

for key, v1, v2 in listY:
    if key not in counter:
        counter[key] = (0, 0)
    counter[key][0] += v1
    counter[key][1] += v2

result = [(key, value[0], value[1]) for key, value in counter.items()]
```

Answer (score 8):

This is pretty easy if you use a dictionary.

```
combined = {}
for item in listX + listY:
    key = item[0] 
    if key in combined:
        combined[key][0] += item[1]
        combined[key][1] += item[2]
    else:
        combined[key] = [item[1], item[2]]

result = [(key, value[0], value[1]) for key, value in combined.items()]
```

Comment: Curses, beat me to a very similar answer by mere seconds!

Comment: it took me a while to understand that he was actually _adding_ values, and not removing duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say use a dictionary:

```
result = {}
for eachlist in (ListX, ListY,):
    for item in eachlist:
        if item[0] not in result:
            result[item[0]] = item
```

It's always tricky do do data manipulation if you have data in a structure that doesn't represent the data well. Consider using better data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary and its 'get' method.

```
d = {}
for x in (listX + listY):
    y       = d.get(x[0], (0, 0, 0))
    d[x[0]] = (x[0], x[1] + y[1], x[2] + y[2])

d.values()
```